# Set up authorized CIDR in Hostinger

Tags: hosting, cidr

I've been trying to set up some authorized CIDRs connections to denie queries from other sites and help our Website with its security, However I havent found the correct way to do it since I do not see options in the Hostinger's portal.

I have checked with Hostinger customer department about this but they said that they dont do that process. Thats why I would like to have instructions or clues to know how I can do it by myself.

I would appreciate if someone knows how to do it, thanks!